# How to set animation to progress bar in Android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-progressbar

I want to create timer progress bar for 1 minute. I've used following code but it is starting from 60 to 0 whereas using same procedure I've to start from 0 to 60.

```
public static void animateTimerProgress(int currentTimeDuration, final int maxTimeDuration, boolean withStartDelay, final DonutProgress timeOutProgressView, Runnable endAction) {
    final int duration = currentTimeDuration < 0 ? 1 : currentTimeDuration;
    timeOutProgressView.setMax(maxTimeDuration);
    timeOutProgressView.setProgress(duration);
    timeOutProgressView.animate()
            .setDuration(duration * SECOND_IN_MILLIS)
            .setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator())
            .setStartDelay(withStartDelay ? TIMEOUT_START_DELAY : 0)
            .setUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                    int progress = 1 + (int) ((1f - valueAnimator.getAnimatedFraction()) * (duration - 1f));

                    timeOutProgressView.setProgress(progress);
                }
            })
            .withEndAction(endAction)
            .start();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

you can use `ValueAnimator` like this

```
ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, 60);
animator.setDuration(duration * SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        timeOutProgressView.setProgress((int) animation.getAnimatedValue());
    }
});
animator.start();
```

Answer (score 4):

On Kotlin, you can use 2 extension functions to help with that, incrementing 1 by 1 on progress. In this way, you can have a smoother animation:

```
/**
 * ProgressBar Extensions
 */
fun ProgressBar.setBigMax(max: Int) {
    this.max = max * 1000
}

fun ProgressBar.animateTo(progressTo: Int, startDelay: Long) {
    val animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(
        this,
        "progress",
        this.progress,
        progressTo * 1000
    )
    animation.duration = 500
    animation.interpolator = DecelerateInterpolator()
    animation.startDelay = startDelay
    animation.start()
}
```

How to use it:

```
 progress.setBigMax(10)
 progress.animateTo(10, 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following code to get your progress

```
int progress = 1 + (int) (valueAnimator.getAnimatedFraction() * (duration - 1f));
```

`valueAnimator.getAnimatedFraction()` gives the fraction value of your animation. You need to multiply by the max progress/duration to get current value of progress.

Comment: Thanks @nitinkumarp

Comment: Mark as accepted if it helped you to solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

make a class

```
 public class Anim {

    public static void fadeOutProgressLayout(Activity act, final ViewGroup progressLayout) {
        act.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
                fadeOut.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
                fadeOut.setDuration(300);

                fadeOut.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener()
                {
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
                    {
                        progressLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
                });

                progressLayout.startAnimation(fadeOut);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and write this line where ever you want the progress to go

```
Anim.fadeOutProgressLayout(GamblingVideosActivity.this, progressLayout);
```